# Calculating total and relative frequency of values in a dict representing a Markov-chain rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, frequency, markov-chains

I have made a function `make_rule(text, scope=1)` that simply goes over a string and generates a dictionary that serves as a rule for a Markovian text-generator (where the scope is the number of linked characters, not words).

```
>>> rule = make_rule("abbcad", 1)
>>> rule
{'a': ['b', 'd'], 'b': ['b', 'c'], 'c': ['a']}
```

I have been tasked with calculating the entropy of this system. In order to do that I think I would need to know:

1. How often a value appears in the dictionary in total, i.e. its total frequency.
2. How often a value appears given a key in the dictionary, i.e. its relative frequency.

Is there a quick way to get both of these numbers for each of the values in the dictionary?

For the above example I would need this output:

```
'a' total: 1, 'a'|'a': 0, 'a'|'b': 0, 'a'|'c': 1
'b' total: 2, 'b'|'a': 1, 'b'|'b': 1, 'b'|'c': 0
'c' total: 1, 'c'|'a': 0, 'c'|'b': 1, 'c'|'c': 0
'd' total: 1, 'd'|'a': 1, 'a'|'b': 1, 'a'|'c': 1
```

I guess the `'a'` total is easily inferred, so maybe instead just output a list of triples for every unique item that appears in the dictionary:

```
[[('a', 'a', 0), ('a', 'b', 0), ('a', 'c', 1)], [('b', 'a', 1), ('b', 'b', 1), ('b', 'c', 0)], ...]
```

Comment: What is the expected result of the above dictionary for each value?

Comment: Oh, sorry, seems I cut away the expected output. I have added it now. The format of the output isn't too important, only how I efficiently can get these numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just deal with "How often a value appears given a key in the dictionary", since you've said that "How often a value appears in the dictionary in total" is easily inferred.

If you just want to be able to look up the relative frequency of a value for a given key, it's easy to get that with a `dict` of [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) objects:

```
from collections import Counter

rule = {'a': ['b', 'd'], 'b': ['b', 'c'], 'c': ['a']}

freq = {k: Counter(v) for k, v in rule.items()}
```

… which gives you a `freq` like this:

```
{
    'a': Counter({'b': 1, 'd': 1}),
    'b': Counter({'b': 1, 'c': 1}),
    'c': Counter({'a': 1})
}
```

… so that you can get the relative frequency of `'a'` given the key `'c'` like this:

```
>>> freq['c']['a']
1
```

Because `Counter` objects return 0 for nonexistent keys, you'll also get zero frequencies as you would expect:

```
>>> freq['a']['c']
0
```

If you need a list of 3-tuples as specified in your question, you can get that with a little extra work. Here's a function to do it:

```
def triples(rule):               
    freq = {k: Counter(v) for k, v in rule.items()}
    all_values = sorted(set().union(*rule.values()))      
    sorted_keys = sorted(rule)
    return [(v, k, freq[k][v]) for v in all_values for k in sorted_keys]
```

The only thing here which I think may not be self-explanatory is the `all_values = ...` line, which:

1. creates an empty [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)
2. produces the [`union()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) of that set with all the individual elements of the lists in `rule.values()` (note the use of the [argument-unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=argument%20unpacking#unpacking-argument-lists) `*` operator)
3. converts the result into a [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) list.

If you still have the original text, you can avoid all that work by using e.g. `all_values = sorted(set(original_text))` instead.

Here it is in action:

```
>>> triples({'a': ['b', 'd'], 'b': ['b', 'c'], 'c': ['a']})
[
    ('a', 'a', 0), ('a', 'b', 0), ('a', 'c', 1),
    ('b', 'a', 1), ('b', 'b', 1), ('b', 'c', 0),
    ('c', 'a', 0), ('c', 'b', 1), ('c', 'c', 0),
    ('d', 'a', 1), ('d', 'b', 0), ('d', 'c', 0)
]
```

Comment: The usage of `Counter` simplifies the task greatly, thank you for a good suggestion! I think this should be the accepted answer, as it goes in-depth and is very informative.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a quick way other than iterating over the word's characters, counting the occurences in each list of the dictionary and summing it in the end:

```
alphabet = sorted(set("abbcad"))
rule = {'a': ['b', 'd'], 'b': ['b', 'c'], 'c': ['a']}

totalMatrix = []
for elem in alphabet:
    total = 0
    occurences = []
    for key in rule.keys():
        currentCount = rule[key].count(elem)
        total += currentCount
        occurences.append((elem,key,currentCount))
    totalMatrix.append([elem, total] + occurences)

for elem in totalMatrix:
    print(elem)
```

The content of `totalMatrix` will be:

```
['a', 1, ('a', 'a', 0), ('a', 'b', 0), ('a', 'c', 1)]
['b', 2, ('b', 'a', 1), ('b', 'b', 1), ('b', 'c', 0)]
['c', 1, ('c', 'a', 0), ('c', 'b', 1), ('c', 'c', 0)]
['d', 1, ('d', 'a', 1), ('d', 'b', 0), ('d', 'c', 0)]
```

Comment: Your suggestion is very clear and simple, thank you!